# XGetImage Failed Error when using python MSS library on Ubuntu

Tags: python, linux, x11, python-mss

I'm encountering an error when using mss, on Ubuntu 18.10 (if that matters). Here's my code (Taken from their examples in the documentation, plus some extra error output):

```
import mss
with mss.mss() as sct:
    try:
        filename = sct.shot(mon=-1, output='fullscreen.png')
        print(filename)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e, "\n", e.details)
```

Here's the output I see when I run the code using python 3.7.

```
XGetImage() failed
 {'retval': <mss.linux.LP_XImage object at 0x7fc72d567bf8>, 'args': (<mss.linux.LP_Display object at 0x7fc72db7d1e0>, <mss.linux.LP_Display object at 0x7fc72d567950>, 0, 0, 1920, 1080, 16777215, 2)}
```

If it helps, here is the output if I don't catch the exception (stacktrace)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "process.py", line 3, in <module>
    filename = sct.shot(mon=-1, output='fullscreen.png')
  File "/home/user/.local/share/virtualenvs/poker-TAtsjijf/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mss/base.py", line 140, in shot
    return next(self.save(**kwargs))
  File "/home/user/.local/share/virtualenvs/poker-TAtsjijf/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mss/base.py", line 129, in save
    sct = self.grab(monitor)
  File "/home/user/.local/share/virtualenvs/poker-TAtsjijf/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mss/linux.py", line 430, in grab
    ZPIXMAP,
  File "/home/user/.local/share/virtualenvs/poker-TAtsjijf/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mss/linux.py", line 171, in validate
    raise ScreenShotError(err, details=details)
mss.exception.ScreenShotError: XGetImage() failed
```

I am running it in a virtual environment, in which my Pipfile.lock reports mss version `4.0.2`.

I have tried running it as root, but that gave the same output. I was unable to find a similar issue in Google. I also tried running it outside of tmux, which also had no result.

Comment: Please extract a [mcve]. Also, since you claim to just run examples, it would be useful if you also checked the upstream bug tracker for reports of similar problems.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt What about this makes it not minimal/complete/verifiable? I took this example from their documentation, yes, but it's a minimal example compared to my hundreds of lines of codebase. I *think* the example is minimal and verifiable, since when I run it I do encounter the same error. What is the issue here?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Also,  I did check bug trackers (as mentioned in the post when I said I googled). This is the only seemingly relevant result I found https://github.com/BoboTiG/python-mss/issues/105 and the issue was closed due to lack of details.

Comment: You fixed the 'C' part of MCVE yourself. Call me picky, but if you didn't verify that this is minimal and complete (you would have found the missing `import`), I'll point out that it's not a MCVE and not bother any further. Concerning the bug report you found, go ahead and get involved, i.e. supply the missing code!

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt It was a formatting issue - apparently if you have the 3 backticks on the same line as your code the first line disappears. As for the bug report, I did file an issue on their github as well.

Answer (score 3):

I have encountered the same problem to you when using Fedora 29. But after inspect the source code, it seems like `mss` uses `x11` instead of `xWayland` to capture the screen and `xWayland` is default in Fedora. Switching the session to use `x11` fixed my problem. The way to switch is mentioned [here](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/quick-docs/configuring-xorg-as-default-gnome-session/).

Answer (score 1):

Reduce the resolution of the screen in the range 700-400 and try it again. You might need to try different values in that range to make it precise.

Comment: Same, I had this error because I wanted to screen a bigger area than my computer screen